# how to get a key value from Json object in node js

Tags: json, parsing, stringify

I want to get the id value from the following json object

```
  answerTag: 
   [ '[{"id":64,"name":"Coronary Artery Disease"}]',
   '[{"id":64,"name":"Coronary Artery Disease"}]' ],
   risk: '1' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found that I had to remove the leading and trailing brackets before calling JSON.parse for it to work. The JSON.parse inside a try-catch didn't fail but just the same I couldn't access the values in the resultant object.

Here's the excerpt. "rows[0]" is the the first row of my MySQL result array

```js
result = JSON.stringify(rows[0])
result = result.replace(/(^\[)/, '');
result =  result.replace(/(\]$)/, '');
try {
  var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error, not a valid JSON string");
}
var my_value = resultObj["my_key"];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a valid JSON
as a valid json should have a key-value pair

```
var  answerTag= 
{
 "key1":{"id":64,"name":"Coronary Artery Disease"},
 "key2":{"id":64,"name":"Coronary Artery Disease"},
 "key3":{risk: '1' }
}
```

So if u want to traverse that ,put it in for loop like this

```
getKeyValueFromJSON(answerTag);

function getKeyValueFromJSON(
   for(var key in obj) {
      alert("Key: " + key + " value: " + obj[key]);
   }
}
```

Or if i am able  to get it 
The formed JSON is like this

```
var obj={ 
  answerTag: [
     '[{"id":64,"name":"Coronary Artery Disease"}]',
     '[{"id":64,"name":"Coronary Artery Disease"}]' ],
  risk: '1'
}
```

So You can use it like this

```
for(var key in obj) {
    for(var innerKey in obj[key]) {
      console.log("Key: " + innerKey + " value: " + obj[key][innerKey]);
   }      
}
```